# Android TextView dynamic size to ellipsize

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

It's possible to ellipsize the textView without settings the maxLine?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
        android:text="@string/sample_text"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I ellipsize this TextView without setting the maxline, as the "orange" view at the bottom has a dynamic size?

[image: Current layout]

### UPDATE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom"
        android:text="@string/sample_text"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried this approach as well and didn't work either.

**EDIT:**
It seems to be not possible to solve.

Comment: add ellipsize in textview and use constraintlayout

Comment: It doesn't works as the maxLine is not defined. I've tried the constraintlayout as well, and also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your textview xml code
 `android:ellipsize="end"`

Comment: Can you try {end | bottom} to the textview ?

Comment: "bottom" is not a params to ellipsize

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:ellipsize="end"`